# Custom Save button on salesforce contract object

Tags: salesforce

I have been trying to use custom save button on contract object . where it should function the standard save functionality. I have tried by using java script where in script i have mentioned end point url . but unable to function clearly.
Any perfect code for it.

Answer (score 0):

you could go to object page and then buttons area. in here you can create a button to point it to anywhere you want. 
then go to your layout and replace save button with the new one.